# Find an array within an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Basically, i'm trying to find an array element within an array object, but it always returning -1.

Here is the code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myArray = [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2]];
  var a = myArray .indexOf([0,1]);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the position of the element "[0,1]":</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convert and compare strings

Strictly comparing objects is false because no two objects are the same. You could convert each array within the array to a string using [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Then use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to instead  find `"0,1"`.

```
[0,1] === [0,1] // false

"0,1" === "0,1" // true
```

---

**The goal:** `["0,1","1,1","1,2"].indexOf("0,1")` which is the intended use of `indexOf()`

---

```js
  
var needle = [0,1].join(); // or "0,1"
var haystack = [ [0,1],[1,1],[1,2] ];
var index = haystack.join('-').split('-').indexOf(needle); 
 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = index ;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

- `.join('-')` produces `"0,1-1,1-1,2"`
- `.split('-')` produces `["0,1", "1,1", "1,2"]`
- `.indexOf("0,1")` produces `0`

---

### Standalone Function

```
var needle = [0,1];
var haystack = [["0,1"],["1,1"],["1,2"]];
var index = getIndex(needle, haystack) // returns 0

function getIndex(needle, haystack) {      
    return haystack.join('-').split('-').indexOf( needle.join() );          
}
```

Comment: how about if needle = [[0,1],[1,2]]? Is there a way to return a boolean true, if both elements have been found?

Comment: `if(getIndex([0,1], haystack) && getIndex([1,2], haystack))` You can easily make a function that loops through multiple parameters. I'm not going to reduce the integrity of the answer though because I spent a good amount of time making it the best I could for the question at hand. :)

Comment: Thanks Brian, this solution will help a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2]];
```

Above line store three array object inside myArray object.

Now you are trying to check the index of a new array on it.

`var a = myArray .indexOf([0,1]);`//Here [0,1] is the new array object,it has different reference

so it will always return -1.

Just for verification,you can do like below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a1 = [0,1];
  var a2 = [1,1];
  var a3 = [1,2];

  var myArray = [a1,a2,a3];
  var a = myArray.indexOf(a1);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the position of the element "[0,1]":</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

it returns 0 ,because here a1 is not new object

Comment: +1 - The only problem would be is if `myArray` needed to be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how javascript compares objects.  Copying from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators):

> Note that an object is converted into a primitive if, and only if, its comparand is a primitive. If both operands are objects, they're compared as objects, and **the equality test is true only if both refer the same object.**

(Don't forget that JS `Array` are technically `Object`).  You can even see this pretty trivially in the browser (assuming you have some sort of dev tools available to you):

```
[0, 1] == [0, 1];  # false -- They're different objects even though they have the same values.
```

but this works because they're the same objects:

```
a = [0, 1];
a == a;  # true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.indexOf()` uses a strict equality comparison `===`. In case of arrays and objects it will never be true unless they're the same instance, you can see that:

```
[0,1] === [0,1] //Returns false
```

[**Reference MDN docs on Comparison**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)

So, you'd have to iterate the array to find the equality index. Something like:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myArray = [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2]];
  var a = -1;
  var find = [0,1];
  
  var idx = 0;
  myArray.map(function(item) {
      var valid = true;
      for(var i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
          if(item[i] !== find[i])
             valid = false;
      }
      if(valid)
          a = idx;
      idx++;
  });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the position of the element "[0,1]":</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```